# Huge quantity of Dask computations causing memory issues

Tags: python, pandas, dask

I am working on a task where I need to determine where two geospatial points are within 250 meters of each other and occur within 20 minutes of each other. My data set is approximately 1.2M rows and 10 columns. So, I need to determine a distance, time difference, and whether they meet my criteria by going through 1.2M**2 calculations.

I have been able to run the code below where I create 10,000 Dask objects to compute without problem. However, when I attempt to test 100,000 objects Dask runs up against memory limitations and I see significant CPU usage for swap. To be clear, I'm running this on a 32 core node with 125 GB of memory.

Admittedly, I'm quite new to Dask, so I'd like to know: is there a better way to solve this problem than processing in 10,000 row chunks?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import dask.dataframe as dd
from dask.array import sqrt
import time
import multiprocessing as mp


df = pd.read_hdf(...) # Used to select single item for comparison
ddf = dd.read_hdf(...) # Used for Dask operations

def distCheck(item,df=ddf):
    '''
    Determine if any records in df are within 250m of item and within 20
    minutes of item. Return Dask object for calculation.
    '''   

    dist = sqrt(((ddf.LCC_x1-item.LCC_x1)**2+(ddf.LCC_y1-item.LCC_y1)**2))
    distcrit = dist[dist < 250]

    delta = (ddf.Date - item.Date).abs()
    timecrit = delta[delta < np.timedelta64(20,'m')]

    res1 = ddf.copy()
    res1['dist'] = dist
    res1['delta'] = delta
    res1 = res1.loc[(distcrit.index) & (timecrit.index) & (idcrit.index)]
    res1['MatchMMSI'] = item.MMSI
    res1['MatchVoy'] = item.Voyage

    out = res1
    return out


def getDaskCalls(start,stop):
    '''
    Get Dask objects to assess temporal and spatial proximity for df 
    indices from start to stop.
    '''
    # Kick off multiprocessing pool, submit, and close    
    pool = mp.Pool(processes=32)

    daskers = []
    for i in range(start,stop):
        result = pool.apply_async(distCheck,args=(df.iloc[i,:],ddf,))
        daskers.append(result)

    dasky = [i.get() for i in daskers]
    pool.close()    
    return dasky


def runDask(calls):
    result = pd.DataFrame([],columns=calls[0].columns)
    output = dd.compute(calls)
    result = pd.concat([result]+[i for i in output[0] if i.shape[0] != 0])

    return result


###
### Process
###

# Get initial timestamp
start = time.time()

# Create Dask Calls & determine duration
dcalls = getDaskCalls(0,10000)
callsCreated = time.time()

# Print time required to create calls
print("Dask Calls Created.")
print(callsCreated-start)

# Compute the calls with Dask
print("Computing...")
result = runDask(dcalls)

# Print the time for computation
computation = time.time()
print("   ...Done.")
print(computation-callsCreated)
```

Comment: Can't help but ask, is it worth considering using something designed for this kind of problem? Like a geospatial database that would store the data points with spatial indexing? Or do the requirements prevent that?

Comment: You don't need to apply the distance calc row-by-row (that's essentially a naive `for` loop). You should do it with array math and fancy indexing. See slides 51+ here: https://speakerdeck.com/jakevdp/losing-your-loops-fast-numerical-computing-with-numpy-pycon-2015

Comment: @paisanco I don't have access to an ESRI license on the server and I am not too familiar with other geospatial database storage methods. Can you recommend one?

Comment: @PaulH Thanks for the tip! I'll put your suggestion to use.

Comment: Some options besides ESRI would include the PostGIS extensions to Postgresql, or the MySQL spatial extensions.